# How to go back to the previous page using a swipe or a back button in WebView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

The old version of WebView package for Flutter had the `gestureNavigationEnabled` option. The package's official page says, “The following features have been moved to an iOS implementation class.”

What about Android? Is there a similar way to go back to the previous page using a swipe or a back button in WebView?

There is a great **[tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#7)** on how to add a menu button to the AppBar. But is it possible to implement a return to the previous page differently on Android devices using Flutter?

Comment: I am interested in how to do this in Flutter.

Comment: ah I see. Now I see since you edited and added Flutter as context.